# Redirect back from Service Provider to idP

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor.AuthServices to implement Service Provider in a Web Forms application.  I am seeing the SP redirect to idP and then POST the SAML to idP.  However, it gets redirected back to idP again.  I am guessing some configuration is not right, but not able to track it down.  [image: redirect sequence]

Comment: I see you'r using my chrome plugin. Nice =). Ok so the SP redirects to the IDP with a SAML Request in the URL. What happens next? you say it POST to the IDP. What does it POST what SAML request?

Comment: @StefanRasmusson very useful plugin!  so this is what happens.  Initial request to SP redirects to idP for login.  then idP posts SAML Request to SP.  SP then redirects back to idP.  I have another sample MVC web app that works just fine against the same idP.

Comment: Ok, is the SAML Responce posted by the IDP successfull?

Comment: Looks like it is.  I don't any errors..checked IIS logs.

Comment: Ok, double check the logs for the SP and the IDP.

Comment: No errors.  I do see the FedAuth cookie being set.  Assuming this happens only after authentication is successful on SP.  The SP application itself is a Sharepoint website, which I think is what is complicating things in this scenario